# Grep '--colorful' parameter is not working

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, redhat

I would like to know the proper syntax for highlighting with more than one color in grep using **--colorful** parameter but it says **--colorful** is unknown option.

Please see my command below:

```
$ grep --colorful color color.txt
grep: unknown option -- colorful
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 4):

The option is called `--color` or `--colour`. Not `--colorful`.

From the [Unix Man pages : grep()](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

```
--colour[=WHEN], --color[=WHEN]
      Surround  the matching string with the marker find in GREP_COLOR
      environment variable. WHEN may be 'never', 'always', or 'auto
```